# Mouse Position Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for the script that does that following. If you visit this website http://wearehunted.com/

If you shift your mouse to the right more data is revealed. Based on the position of the mouse left or right, more data is revealed. I tried pulling the source of the website, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What could you not find? Didn't you understand something specific in the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
window.onmousemove = function(e){
    var e = e || event;
    var x = e.screenX;
    var y = e.screenY;
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) script, just a simple slider. If you move your mouse into a region on the left/right side, it scrolls in that direction.

You can find the jQuery plugin source at http://media2.wearehunted.com/media/js/jquery.draggrid.js?v=21824